# Is it possible to use .includes for an associative array/array of hashes?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a following array that needs to use .includes to check if their is an object that has duplicate or none. The problem is it always returns false so I'm not sure if there is a correct way or .includes can't be used this way.

```js
var array_rooms = [{
    type: "Heritage",
    n: 1
  }, {
    type: "Hanuono",
    n: 1
  }, {
    type: "Bangon",
    n: 1
  }, {
    type: "Heritage",
    n: 1
  }]
console.log(array_rooms.includes("Heritage"));
//should return true
```

Comment: No, you'll have to look through the objects with your own code. You can use the `.some()` method.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't have an "associative array" or an "array of hashes". You have an array of objects (which is the closest you'll get to an associative array in JavaScript).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`includes` is well-suited to search for primitives. You should use `some` to check for inner properties of objects:

```js
var rooms = [{
  type: "Heritage",
  n: 1
}, {
  type: "Hanuono",
  n: 1
}, {
  type: "Bangon",
  n: 1
}, {
  type: "Heritage",
  n: 1
}]

console.log(rooms.some(item => item.type === "Heritage"));
```